# Changing Devise's id to Name in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, routes

I'm searching a lot on how to Change the Default URL of *user/1* **to** *user/username*.

I have a :name Field on my Registration form and want that Input to be shown in the url in place of the :id.

A :name input e.g.: **The Mini John**,(site.com/user/theminijohn) how does ruby handle it so there wont be spaces or uppercase Letters?

How do i configure this in Devise?

**Edit**

I searched all the guides here on stackoverflow and on google but for some reason i'm not getting it, Its probably a small problem that i'm overlooking.

PLEASE HELP ME :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have slugged the username column. You can use Norman gem [FriendlyId](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id) its very simple have a look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) and .

Comment: Does it work with Devise? Sry for my noobish Questions, i'm new to rails.

Comment: Yes, it does work. You are creating slug from first name and last name of a user using friendlyId, devise has nothing to do with it.